# Ordering|Sorting records with condition in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, activerecord

I want to order my records with a condition. Lets say i have a `Model`. And fields are `[x,y,z]`.

These are all string typed colums. I want to sort records by condition

```
z = "YGS-1" and y DESC
```

for example. So z has a condition if value is "YGS-1" and y with DESC condition.
How can i sort|order my records. with these conditions.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 3:

```
Model.where(:z => 'YGS-1').order('y DESC')
```

Comment: How can you do the same where (:z => NOT 'YGS-1')?

Comment: You can use a string instead:  `where("z != 'YGS-1'")` or with bound parameters: `where("z != ?", foo)`

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume your model is called `Item`:

```
@items = Item.where(:z => "YGS-1").order("y DESC")
```